# Android: Drawing lines using onDraw and onTouchEvent render slow

Tags: android, android-custom-view, touch-event, ondraw, custom-view

I am trying to draw four lines using the ontouch method and onDraw method like below:

```
 @Override
       protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        initPoints();
        path.reset();
        path.addCircle(topLeftPoint.x,topLeftPoint.y, 16f,       
       Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.drawLines(points, paint);

        path.addCircle(middleTopPoint.x, middleTopPoint.y, 16f, Path.Direction.CW);
        path.addCircle(topRightPoint.x, topRightPoint.y, 16f, Path.Direction.CW);

//      canvas.drawLine(topRightPoint.x, topRightPoint.y, bottomRightPoint.x, bottomRightPoint.y, paint);
        path.addCircle(bottomRightPoint.x, bottomRightPoint.y, 16f, Path.Direction.CW);

        path.addCircle(middleRightPoint.x, middleRightPoint.y, 16f, Path.Direction.CW);
//      canvas.drawLine(bottomRightPoint.x, bottomRightPoint.y, bottomLeftPoint.x, bottomLeftPoint.y, paint);
        path.addCircle(bottomLeftPoint.x, bottomLeftPoint.y, 16f, Path.Direction.CW);
        path.addCircle(middleBottomPoint.x, middleBottomPoint.y, 16f, Path.Direction.CW);

//      canvas.drawLine(bottomLeftPoint.x, bottomLeftPoint.y, topLeftPoint.x, topLeftPoint.y, paint);
        path.addCircle(topRightPoint.x, topRightPoint.y, 16f, Path.Direction.CW);
        path.addCircle(middleLeftPoint.x, middleLeftPoint.y, 16f, Path.Direction.CW);
        path.close();
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
            }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {

        int action = event.getActionMasked();

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ||
                event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
                || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            float xCoordinate = 16;
            float yCoordinate = 16;

            if (event.getX() < 16) {
                xCoordinate = 16;
            } else if (event.getX() > getWidth() - 16) {
                xCoordinate = getWidth() - 16;
            } else {
                xCoordinate = event.getX();
            }

            if (event.getY() < 16) {
                yCoordinate = 16;
            } else if (event.getY() > getHeight() - 16) {
                yCoordinate = getHeight() - 16;
            } else {
                yCoordinate = event.getY();
            }
            if (isInsideTopLeft(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                topLeftPoint.set(xCoordinate, yCoordinate);

                middleTopPoint.set((topRightPoint.x + topLeftPoint.x) / 2,
                        (topRightPoint.y + topLeftPoint.y) / 2);
                middleLeftPoint.set((bottomLeftPoint.x + topLeftPoint.x) / 2,
                        (bottomLeftPoint.y + topLeftPoint.y) / 2);
                invalidate();
                return true;
            } else if (isInsideTopRight(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                topRightPoint.set(xCoordinate, yCoordinate);

                middleTopPoint.set((topRightPoint.x + topLeftPoint.x) / 2,
                        (topRightPoint.y + topLeftPoint.y) / 2);
                middleRightPoint.set((bottomRightPoint.x + topRightPoint.x) / 2,
                        (bottomRightPoint.y + topRightPoint.y) / 2);
                invalidate();
                return true;
            } else if (isInsideBottomRight(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                bottomRightPoint.set(xCoordinate, yCoordinate);

                middleBottomPoint.set((bottomLeftPoint.x + bottomRightPoint.x) / 2,
                        (bottomLeftPoint.y + bottomRightPoint.y) / 2);
                middleRightPoint.set((bottomRightPoint.x + topRightPoint.x) / 2,
                        (bottomRightPoint.y + topRightPoint.y) / 2);
                invalidate();
                return true;
            } else if (isInsideBottomLeft(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                bottomLeftPoint.set(xCoordinate, yCoordinate);

                middleBottomPoint.set((bottomLeftPoint.x + bottomRightPoint.x) / 2,
                        (bottomLeftPoint.y + bottomRightPoint.y) / 2);
                middleLeftPoint.set((bottomLeftPoint.x + topLeftPoint.x) / 2,
                        (bottomLeftPoint.y + topLeftPoint.y) / 2);
                invalidate();
                return true;
            } 
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

but when i am increasing the touching speed the render became slower.
I already used paths and lines but the increasing performance is still small.

The rest of methods i removed from the code such as declaring the PointF objects and initiating those objects with default values.

If someone have any idea i will appreciate.

Best Regards,
AurelianR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not performance related, it's about wrong execution of touch-handling. Touch-handling concept in brief : your view gets following touch event's

ACTION_DOWN : received (one-time) when user places their finger on your view. Always generated.

ACTION_MOVE : received (multiple times) when user moves finger. If user doesn't move their finger then this event is not generated.

ACTION_UP : received (one time)when user lifts finger from your view. Always generated.

DOWN till UP completes one cycle of touch event, user can touch your view multiple times.

Your code :

```
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ||
            event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
            || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

    if(isInsideTopLeft()){
    // do something
    // return
    } 
    // do same for other cases also.
}
```

this way you are computing your cases every time(isInsideTopLeft() etc.), which is resulting in dropping touch event(event not covered by any case). what you should do instead is lock touch event for a particular case in ACTION_DOWN, then simply move your view in ACTION_MOVE and finally in ACTION_UP release touch lock.

Working Code follows :

```
//create touch lock cases 
private final int TOUCH_STATE_UNLOCKED = 0;
private final int TOUCH_STATE_LOCKED_TOP_LEFT = 1;
private final int TOUCH_STATE_LOCKED_TOP_RIGHT = 2;
private final int TOUCH_STATE_LOCKED_BOTTOM_LEFT = 3;
private final int TOUCH_STATE_LOCKED_BOTTOM_RIGHT = 4;
private final int TOUCH_STATE_LOCKED_MIDDLE_LEFT = 5;
private final int TOUCH_STATE_LOCKED_MIDDLE_BOTTOM = 6;

private int TOUCH_STATE = TOUCH_STATE_UNLOCKED;

 @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {

    int action = event.getActionMasked();
    float xCoordinate = 16;
    float yCoordinate = 16;
    int eventX = (int) event.getX();
    int eventY = (int) event.getY();

    if (eventX < 16) {
        xCoordinate = 16;
    } else if (eventX > getWidth() - 16) {
        xCoordinate = getWidth() - 16;
    } else {
        xCoordinate = eventX;
    }

    if (eventY < 16) {
        yCoordinate = 16;
    } else if (eventY > getHeight() - 16) {
        yCoordinate = getHeight() - 16;
    } else {
        yCoordinate = eventY;
    }

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        /* Touch event handling in brief,  read about touch event handling,

        in ACTION_DOWN lock touch event for a particular point.


         */
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            // lock touch event for a point . subsequent touch events
            if (isInsideTopLeft(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                TOUCH_STATE = TOUCH_STATE_LOCKED_TOP_LEFT;
            } else if (isInsideTopRight(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                TOUCH_STATE = TOUCH_STATE_LOCKED_TOP_RIGHT;
            } else if (isInsideBottomLeft(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                TOUCH_STATE = TOUCH_STATE_LOCKED_BOTTOM_LEFT;
            } else if (isInsideBottomRight(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                TOUCH_STATE = TOUCH_STATE_LOCKED_BOTTOM_RIGHT;
            } else if (isInsideMiddleLeft(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                TOUCH_STATE = TOUCH_STATE_LOCKED_MIDDLE_LEFT;
            } else if (isInsideMiddleBottom(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                TOUCH_STATE = TOUCH_STATE_LOCKED_MIDDLE_BOTTOM;
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "onTouchEvent: TOUCH_STATE = " + TOUCH_STATE);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
// simply check for locked case
            if (TOUCH_STATE == TOUCH_STATE_LOCKED_TOP_LEFT) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onTouchEvent: top left locked");
                topLeftPoint.set(xCoordinate, yCoordinate);

                middleTopPoint.set((topRightPoint.x + topLeftPoint.x) / 2,
                        (topRightPoint.y + topLeftPoint.y) / 2);
                middleLeftPoint.set((bottomLeftPoint.x + topLeftPoint.x) / 2,
                        (bottomLeftPoint.y + topLeftPoint.y) / 2);
                // working fine with full invalidate also.
                invalidate();
            }
            // handle other cases also
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            TOUCH_STATE = TOUCH_STATE_UNLOCKED;  // unlock

    }
    return true;
}
```

One small performance optimization possibility found, for that I am creating branch in GitHub and opening a pull request.

Comment: perfect, absolutely perfect

Answer (score 1):

Without complete code it's very difficult to inspect possible areas for improvement. 
You are calling initPoints() and also resetting path on every draw call.

If we consider the following case in touch Event :

```
if (isInsideTopLeft(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
      // update topLeftPoint, middleTopPoint and middleLeftPoint.
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
```

then in onDraw()

```
path.reset();  // may be not necessary.
path.addCircle(topLeftPoint.x, topLeftPoint.y, 16f,
            Path.Direction.CW);  // point changed
path.addCircle(middleTopPoint.x, middleTopPoint.y,16f,Path.Direction.CW);//point changed
path.addCircle(middleLeftPoint.x, middleLeftPoint.y, 16f,Path.Direction.CW);// point changed
```

Only three calls have updated rest 6 path updates can be avoided. postInvalidate(dirtyRect) can be used.
If you add complete code(along with basic comments), then I can inspect by running it.

Comment: i will share entire project on github

Comment: Okay, add basic comments also to give me headstart

Comment: https://github.com/aurelianr/CustomView here is the code of the project.